# android - hidden file

Tags: java, android

I'm having a trouble with my Android application developed with Eclipse.

The problem is that when I capture a new image using the folowing instructions:

```
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_IMAGE);
```

The device stores the file correctly in the right `destination(extSdCard)`, but the following code which is supposed to reload the directory content doesn't find the new files until the device is rebooted.

```
   images.clear();
   final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
   final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
   String condition = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like '%/"+
   Singleton.getCurrentPatient().getNrdo()+"/%'";

   Cursor imagecursor =  getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                condition, null, orderBy);

    if(imagecursor != null){
     int image_column_index = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
     int count = imagecursor.getCount();
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
           int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
           ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
          imageItem.id = id;
          lastId = id;
          imageItem.img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
         images.add(imageItem);
     }
       imagecursor.close();
     }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Any idea about that? Must we do a commit to refresh some cache?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) to notify the system of new media files. `MediaScanner` also runs as part of boot sequence so that's why you see the files appearing in `MediaStore` after a reboot.